# How to remove imports from nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a VueJS + Nuxt app where I have to make a page where all assets are actually inline

So instead of the normal imports of

```
<script src="/_nuxt/hash.js"></script>
```

i would need the js or css to be written directly inside the tags

```
<script>the content of hash.js</script>
```

I haven't been able to find anything on this. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: After build , copy the code from js file to script tag

Comment: .... i'm talking about something automated, preferably directly from nuxt

Comment: Why do you need all assets inlined?

Comment: Can you guys just help me instead of questioning the need? That is the requirement for that page to not have any imports regarding js and css